# How can I read and write the field in firestore for each user?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I need to read the field from firestore for each user. How can I do this? I'm using vuefire. I found this code, but how do I refer to the field in the document? Let's say a field called spin

```
firestore(){
   return{
   chance: db.collection('users').doc()
}
```

Comment: You can only write to a document once you know its completely path. So you'll have to read all documents, loop over them, and then update them one by one.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen if i will  use this  
chance: db.collection('users').doc(user.uid) how can i read the field?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you asking how to [read data from Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data)?